# R: suppress notation using matrices inside felm()

Tags: r

Using felm() - package(lfe)

I have 10 variables, and would like the own and interacted effects.

When building a reproducible data frame, however, I am able to get the script to run as follows:

```
library(lfe)

## build data frame
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(1:10000),x2=rnorm(1:10000),x3=rnorm(1:10000),x4=rnorm(1:10000),x5=rnorm(1:10000),
  z1 = rnorm(1:10000),z2=rnorm(1:10000),z3=rnorm(1:10000),z4=rnorm(1:10000),z5=rnorm(1:10000),
  f1 = as.factor(sample(c("yes","no","maybe"),10000,replace=TRUE)),
  f2 = as.factor(sample(c("high","med","low"),10000,replace=TRUE)),
  y  = rnorm(1:10000))

## build matrices
x <- select(data,starts_with("x"))
z <- select(data,starts_with("z"))

## run model
model <- felm(y ~ as.matrix(x)*as.matrix(z) | factor(f1)+factor(f2) | 0 | f1, data=data)
summary(model)
```

This executes nicely. However, using this exact structure in my real data, I am returned the error:

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
>       replacement has 367060 rows, data has 73412

It appears to be using a product of the matrix instead:

> n = 73,412;
>   p = 5;
>   np = 73,412x5 = 367,060

My model:

```
new   <- select(snow,starts_with("new"))  ##results in object 5x73,412
base  <- select(snow,starts_with("base")) ##results in object 5x73,412

model <- felm(price ~ as.matrix(new)*as.matrix(base) | factor(ID) | 0 | ID, data=snow)
```

The objects resulting from `select()` are correct in the desired dimensions (5 x 73,412)

Comment: I have also attempted to use the "." notation directly: `felm(price ~ base$.*new$. |...)` resulting in the error: `Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : <text>:1:15: unexpected numeric constant 1: ~ base$0 ^ `

Answer (score 1):

Using this structure, the solution I found to work was `data.matrix()`

```
## build matrices
x <- select(data,starts_with("x"))
z <- select(data,starts_with("z"))

## run model using matrix notation
model <- felm(y ~ data.matrix(x)*data.matrix(z) | factor(f1)+factor(f2) | 0 | f1, data=data)
```